# Bloom filter hashes: more or bigger?

Tags: ds.data-structures, it.information-theory, hash-function

In implementing a Bloom filter, the traditional approach calls for multiple independent hash functions.  [Kirsch and Mitzenmacher](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~michaelm/postscripts/esa2006a.pdf) showed that you actually only need two, and can generate the rest as linear combinations thereof.

My question is: what, really, is the difference between two hash functions and one with twice the entropy?

This comes from looking at what you actually do with the output of your hash functions: you're going to take your (say) 64-bit hash value and scale it to the size of your bit vector, which is probably significantly smaller than 2<sup>64</sup>.  This is clearly an entropy-losing transformation (except in the rare case your hash size and filter capacity exactly coincide).  Assuming my filter has less than 2<sup>32</sup> entries, what's to stop me from splitting my 64-bit hash value into two 32-bit hashes and taking linear combinations of those?  Or using it to seed a PRNG?

In other words, how much information do I actually need to know about each element I insert into a Bloom filter to ensure the standard false positive rate holds?  Or more generally, what is the relationship between how well I can distinguish elements (how many bits I use to describe them) and how my Bloom filter performs?

It sure seems like I can get away with $2\lg(m)$ bits for a filter size of $m$, or equivalently $2(\lg(-n\ln{p}) - 2\lg(\ln2))$ bits to store $n$ elements with false positive probability $p$....

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're right to think of hash functions in terms of "random bits produced".  So if you have a hash function that produces a 64 bit hash, you can treat is as 4 16-bit hashes (by splitting), and so on.

For the scheme described above (which should be attributed to Dillinger and Manolios;  Kirsch/Mitzenmacher just analyzed it), that means you're correct; if you have a single hash function with $2 \lg(m)$ bits, you should be fine.

Comment: Welcome to cstheory, Michael :)